# Link To SQL Join Statement with or Clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have to following SQL Statement that I want to conver to LINQ

```
Select
  F.FooName
  B.BarName
From Foo F
Inner Join Bar B on B.BarName = F.FooName OR B.BarName + 'hello' = F.FooName
```

I have seen Inner joins in Link on multiple conditions with AND Clauses but not using OR
The following is as far as I have gotten

```
var myresult = from f in Foo
               join b in Bar
                   on new {Name = B.BarName, NamePlus = B.BarName + "hello"} equals
                      new {Name = F.FooName, NamePlus = F.FooName}
               select new { f, b }
```

Clearly this is not right.  Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myresult = from f in foo
               from b in bar
               where b.BarName == f.FooName ||
                     b.BarName + 'hello' == F.FooName
               select new {f, b};
```

Comment: +1; this is the right approach. As a general rule, never use `join` in LINQ to SQL/LINQ to Entities: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/